# Django template - set variable in for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using this code in my templatetags:

http://pastie.org/3530409

And I know for context problem and bad design (that this logic should not be in view) but I need in template solution for this:

```
{% for tag in page.tagname_list %}
        {% ifequal tag "wiki" %}
            {% set howto = 1 %} 
        {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

So I can use howto variable latter for my view logic.

Is there any way to do this in view templates, without model modification ?
If answer yes, please provide some solution...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having to set the variable, you could just do:

```
{% if "wiki" in page.tagname_list %}

     # do your wiki stuff below.

{% endif %}
```

Comment: :) No problem.  The containment lookup is fast enough to not have to worry about performance.